# Monthly, Biannual, Annual Totals Access 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007, reporting

I'm helping out a charity with some of their IT needs. They're not exactly the most technology-gifted people I've met and they're eager to get a rolling total of their visitors in monthly, biannually and annually forms.

They currently have a database setup like this:

Where U is the unique ID, Date is the date and V is the visitor numbers.

U | Date     | V

1 | 23/02/14 | 15

2 | 24/02/14 | 17

3 | 02/03/14 | 25

How would I be able to total these up into the output they want? I'm familiar with SQL but new to Access itself - I've gotten used to MS Management Studio and the server-side stuff. The issue I have with the SQL is being able to separate the yearly and biannually figures from the dates.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**[Edit 1]**

I've tried the SQL code given below, but get a circular reference with the VistCount.

```
SELECT
    VisitYear,
    VisitHalfYear,
    VisitMonth,
    SUM(VisitCount) AS VisitCount
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        YEAR([Day/Date]) AS VisitYear,
        MONTH([Day/Date]) AS VisitMonth,
        IIF(MONTH([Day/Date]) < 7, 1,2) AS VisitHalfYear,
        [Number of Attendees] AS VisitCount
    FROM [Attendees]) 
GROUP BY
    VisitYear,
    VisitHalfYear,
    VisitMonth
```

Comment: Is the back end an Access Jet db, or a SQL Server DB? I can't tell from the question.

Comment: What should the output look like based on the sample input?

Comment: It's just a database stored within Access, there is no server. Because they're a charity the can't afford to store the detail centrally. The db is only the Access saved file and so I'm limited to access's features.

Comment: Ideally I think they'd like the output to be on an Access form. But really whatever output's the easiest I dont think They'd mind as much. A simple table showing the monthly totals would do fine.

Answer (score 1):

Create a saved query in Access similar to this:

```
SELECT
    VisitYear,
    VisitHalfYear,
    VisitMonth,
    SUM(VisitCount) AS VisitCount
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        YEAR([Date]) AS VisitYear,
        MONTH([Date]) AS VisitMonth,
        IIF(MONTH([Date]) < 7, 1,2) AS VisitHalfYear,
        V AS VisitCount
    FROM Table) t
GROUP BY
    VisitYear,
    VisitHalfYear,
    VisitMonth
```

Rather than a form, I recommend using a report for the layout, where your control source is the query. You can can add report groups for Year, Half Year, and Month and lay it out in a readable format. Get subtotals by adding a textbox control with a formula of =SUM(VisitCount) at the Half Year and Year header/footer.

Comment: Use a different alias for `SUM(VisitCount)` --> `SUM(VisitCount) AS SumOfVisitCount` will work.  If you really want to re-use *VisitCount* as the alias, Access *might* accept it in square brackets: `SUM(VisitCount) AS [VisitCount]`

Comment: @HansUp is right. I don't have Access in front of me, and was working from memory. The other option is to keep the 't' alias for the subquery, and preface the select fields in the outer query with 't.fieldname'.